# R mean sorted by groups plot line diagram with ggplot

Tags: r, line, mean, diagram

I have some data like this. At the end there will be 20 trainings.

```
Intensitaet.Auswertung <- data_Auswertung [, c("Type", "training1", "training2", "training3", "training4", "training5")] 

    group                   `training1`    `training2`    `training3`    `training4`    `training5`
   <chr>                       <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Group1                        6              6              4              2              8
 2 Group1                        4              5              5              5              7
 3 Group2                        5              3              3              3              6
 4 Group1                        5              3              4              3              6
 5 Group1                        5              7              8              6              7
 6 Group2                        4              3              4              5              7
 7 Group2                        5              5              5              5              7
 8 Group1                        7              8              6              5              8
 9 Group2                        3              4              4              4              8
10 Group2                        6              5              4              5              4
# ... with 11 more rows
```

I want to plot a line diagram with the **mean** of every training, soreted by groups.

I hope somebody can help me, im very new in R.

Comment: so you want a column mean? if so `ergebniss_df<-apply(Intensitaet.Auswertung[,2:length(Intensitaet.Auswertung)], 2, mean)` is what you are looking for

Comment: i want to sort the mean by the groups. There should be 2 numbers for every column, Group 1 and Group2. So close, but not correct

Comment: ahh i missed that you have 2 groups. wouldn't it be easier to just separate the 2 groups into different df?

if you want more concrete help, my advice would be to upload a small part of your df. you can use `dput()`. then we can work with the data instead of guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
Intensitaet.Auswertung %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "training", values_to = "mean") %>% 
    mutate(training = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",training))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=training, y = mean, group = group, color = group)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, exactly. If i copy this lines, i get an error
`Fehler: Must group by variables found in .data.
* Column group is not found.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: i got it, it was something with big letters in the xlsx

Answer (score 0):

there are ways to do it but i can't say for sure without trying to fiddle with it for a minute or 2. there are people here who can but it is generally preferred to work with a small reproducible df from the op. you could use the `mutate()` command from dplyr/tidyverse or you could use the apply() function with a separate function inside like so:

`df<-apply(your_data, 2, function(x) if (your_data[,1]=="Group1") {mean} else {mean})`
but tbh i have no idea if it works without testing it first. you can also use the `which()` command or the `ifelse()` like so:

`df<-ifelse(your_data[,1]=="Group1", mean(yourdata[,2:length(your_data)]), mean(yourdata[,2:length(your_data)]))`

but again no idea if it works without trying/fiddling

Comment: my original file is a xlsx data, I have created a varable      `data_auswertung`      from this xlsx. I tried     `dput(data_auswertung)`      and     `dput(Intensitaet.Auswertung)`     but im to new in R to get it solved. I want to give you the data, so you can try it, as you said

Comment: to create a reproducible sub-part of your data this works well:

`f<-dput(head(Intensitaet.Auswertung))

write.csv(f, file="C:/...../test")`

Comment: you don't need to upload it, after dput() you can just copy-paste the result you find in your R-console into your question as plain text

Answer (score 0):

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iF4e.png)
`Intensitaet.Auswertung %>%`
  `group_by(group) %>%`
  `summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>%`
  `pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "training", values_to = "mean") %>%`
  `mutate(training = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",training))) %>%`
  `ggplot(aes(x=training, y = mean, group = group, color = group)) +`
  `geom_line() +`
  `scale_colour_manual(values = c("lightskyblue", "royalblue"), name = "Legende") +`
  `ggtitle("Persönliches Intensitäslevel pro Training sortiert nach Gruppen") +`
  `theme_bw() +`
  `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +`
  `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, angle = 90)) +`
  `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust=1)) +`
  `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15)) +`
  `scale_y_continuous(name = "Intensität", breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) +`
  `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`

Now i have this nice Lineplot.
I want to change x any y axis Title and the breaks on the x axis.

Comment: got it with the `scale_x...`